# TeeChart VCL vs .NET

Tags: .net, c++, teechart

Is TeeChart .NET built from the same source as TeeChart VCL? I'm just wandering as we have a VCL application heavily dependent on TeeChart and I would like to redevelop the GUI component in .NET so I can switch from the Codegear IDE to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Framework and VCL are two very, very different libraries.  The different versions of TeeChart would not be built on the same source, although they likely *will* have very similar APIs.